# About the birational maps between surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S^{'}$ and $S$ two complex algebraic projective surfaces. Suppose that there exist an étale cover $p:S^{'}\rightarrow S$ with connected fibers. Now suppose that $S^{'}$ is ruled. is it true that $S$ is also ruled?

Comment: "Etale cover with connected fibres" is a condition that does not really make sense. Remember, an etale cover is like a topological covering space!

Comment: I guess from the title that $p$ is _not_ really supposed to be etale. Anyway, if $p$ is _either_ an etale cover or has connected fibres, then yes, if $S'$ is birationally ruled then so too is $S$.

Comment: and the birational map that makes $S$ ruled is the composition of the invers of the cover $p$ and the birational maps of $S^{'}$?